# How to repeat the same Promise in NodeJS with an Array input until it resolves or the Array ends?

Tags: node.js

I have an array of URLs for the same audio file which are not always working due to server loads.
So, whenever a URL is needed, I should check first the headers of the first URL to make sure it's working now.
If it's not working, I check the next URL.. and so on until the array ends.

**My question is:**
How to chain a recurring of the same Promise (different URL each time) with the ability to break the chain once a working URL is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working as following:

```
function audioPicker(audioUrlArray, i){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        audioUrlCheck(audioUrlArray[i])
            .then(isAvailable =>{
                if(isAvailable) resolve(audioUrlArray[i])
                else if (i+1 < audioUrlArray.length){
                    audioPicker(audioUrlArray, i+1)
                    .then(pick => resolve(pick))
                    .catch(e => reject(e))
                } else reject ('All audio files are not available.')
            })
            .catch(e => log("AuidoPicker Error: ", e)) // Don't reject here
    })
}
    
    
function audioUrlCheck(url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        axios.head(url) // Using axios as "fetch" is not built-in in NodeJS
        .then(r =>{
            log('Fetched audio file URL headers.')
            if(r.headers['content-type'] == 'audio/mpeg') resolve(true)
            else resolve(false)
        })
        .catch(e => resolve(false)) // No reject if Url request failed
    })
}

audioPicker (urlArray, 0)
    .then(pick => resolve(pick))
    .catch(e => reject(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

While a recursive Promise-returning function would be simple enough...

```
const getWorkingAudio = (i = 0) => {
  if (i === urls.length) {
    throw new Error('All URLs bad');
  }
  return fetch(urls[i])
    .then(validateHeaders)
    .catch((error) => {
      return getWorkingAudio(i + 1);
    });
};
getWorkingAudio()
  .then(handleSuccess)
  .catch(handleError);
```

It's a pretty bad sign if you often have so many URLs that may be bad due to server load - better to fix/improve the server than to have developers have to work on silly workarounds like this.

Answer (score 0):

could you add a lil more of context ?

```
 async function checkLinks (links) {
    for (const link of links) {
        try {
             const content = await your checkingThingy()
            // If we are here it means isValid has your BitTorrent or so

             return content
         }  catch (e){}
     }

     // Not found
}
```

That can help you out but if by any means you get some issues make sure to have the proper babel plugins to handle a for of